# Apply Filter on __ob__: Observer (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, devextreme

I want to apply filter like
**this.Grid.option("dataSource").filter(x => x.Placeholder != null)**

but it is not working

when I do

**console.log(this.Grid.option("dataSource"));**

I get

(72) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, **ob**: Observer]
0:
{**ob**: Observer}
1:
Placeholder
:
(...)
PlaceholderDescr
:
(...)
RecordID
:
(...)
**ob**
:
Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get Placeholder
:
ƒ reactiveGetter()
set Placeholder
:
ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get PlaceholderDescr
:
ƒ reactiveGetter()
set PlaceholderDescr
:
ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get RecordID
:
ƒ reactiveGetter()
set RecordID
:
ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
**proto**
:
Object
2
:
{**ob**: Observer}

Answer (score 0):

Get DataSource instance via `ds = this.Grid.getDataSource()` ([documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Methods/#getDataSource))

Then you can filter ds via `ds.filter(expr)` method. For more information, you can inspect [this topic](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Layer/#Reading_Data/Filtering)

Comment: this.Grid.getDataSource() only returns values present on single page. I want values from all the pages of the grid,  this.Grid.option("dataSource") does that. But the issue is that filter gets called before all the data is loaded